# Number of rows returned in a sqlite statement

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

Is there any easy way to get the number of rows returned by a sqlite statement?  I don't want to have to go through the process of doing a COUNT() first.  Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On each call to `sqlite_step`, increment a variable by 1.

If you want the row count *in advance*, then there's no easy way.

Comment: Thanks dan, incrementing the variable seems to be the easiest way.

Comment: This is bad news. I want to malloc an array to store the result, and I can't know how big it needs to be in advance without calling the same select statement twice!

Answer (score 1):

To count all entries in a table, you can use the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "mytable" where something=42;
```

Or just the following to get all entries:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "mytable";
```

In case you have already done the query, and just want the number of entries returned you can use `sqlite3_data_count()` and s`qlite3_column_count()` depending on what you want to count.

Comment: The OP specifically asked for a way to *avoid* `COUNT`.

Comment: Both `sqlite3_data_count` and `sqlite3_column_count` return the number of columns, the former for the current row, the latter for the statement itself. In particular, there is no function in SQLite to tell you how many rows a statement will return, because it doesn't know. You have to iterate over the rows, or do a separate `COUNT(*)` query.