# Fast number of rows in Sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a single table in an Sqlite DB, with many rows. I need to get the number of rows (total count of items in the table).

I tried `select count(*) from table`, but that seems to access each row and is super slow.

I also tried `select max(rowid) from table`. That's fast, but not really safe -- ids can be re-used, table can be empty etc. It's more of a hack.

Any ideas on how to find the table size **quickly and cleanly**?

---

Using Python 2.5's sqlite3 version 2.3.2, which uses Sqlite engine 3.4.0.

Comment: @dan04: found related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822524/number-of-rows-returned-in-a-sqlite-statement -- anyone knows how to do that `sqlite_step` in Python?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any kind of index on a not-null column (for example a primary key)? If yes, the index can be scanned (which hopefully does not take that long). If not, a full table scan is the only way to count all rows.

Comment: Yes, there is a primary key (I don't think that makes much difference here, though).

Answer (score 1):

Other way to get the rows number of a table is by using a trigger that stores the actual number of rows in other table (each insert operation will increment a counter). 
In this way inserting a new record will be a little slower, but you can immediately get the number of rows.

Comment: Care to provide an example? It's hard to accept such hand-wavy answer :) Let's assume a simple `CREATE TABLE (key TEXT PRIMARY KEY, value BLOB)`, for the sake of concreteness.

Comment: It's very simple. You have the table: 

`CREATE TABLE mytable (<all of your columns>)`. 

You would also have to create another table: 

`CREATE TABLE  stats (table_name TEXT PRIMARY KEY, num_rows INTEGER)`.

In 'stats' table each row represents a table along its rows number. By default num_rows equals 0.

When you modify the table `mytable` (insert,delete) you will also have to access `stats` table and increment (or decrement if you perform a delete) by 1 the column num_rows for table_name=`mytable`.

Comment: @Radim: You must also take deletions into account.  SQLite supports `for each row` triggers: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on Thilo's answer, as a data point, I have a sqlite table with 2.3 million rows. Using `select count(*) from table`, it took over 3 seconds to count the rows. I also tried using `SELECT rowid FROM table`, (thinking that rowid is a default primary indexed key) but that was no faster. Then I made an index on one of the fields in the database (just an arbitrary field, but I chose an integer field because I knew from past experience that indexes on short fields can be very fast, I think because the index is stored a copy of the value in the index itself). `SELECT my_short_field FROM table` brought the time down to less than a second.